# Completeness proof.

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm getting stuck showing a space is a Hilbert space. For $\Omega$ an open, connected and bounded set in $\Bbb R^2$ with regular boundary $\partial \Omega$, let $V=\{v \in H^1(\Omega)\ ;\ \int_{\partial\Omega} vdx = 0\}$. Consider the norm $u \to \| \,|\nabla u| \,\|_{L^2}$. (i.e. a semi-norm on $H^1(\Omega)$). Show $V$ is a Hilbert space with respect to this norm. 
I've looked at the proof that V is complete with respect to the norm in $H_1(\Omega)$, but it doesn't work with this norm.

I've considered using the Poincare-Wirtinger inequality (I can add a hypothesis to $\Omega$):
If D is open/bounded/connected/Lipschitz in $\Bbb R$, then there is a constant C such that $\| \,u-u_D\,\|_{L^2(D)} \le C\| \,|\nabla u| \,\|_{L^2(D)},$ where $u_D = \frac 1{|D|}\int_D u(x)dx. $

I just need to show V is complete with respect to this norm (the semi-norm on $H^1(\Omega)$). I think it is, because my professor specifically pointed me toward this norm. I need to show some other properties of the space with the norm afterwards, but don't want to waste my time before I'm sure it's a Hilbert space (because if not I need a different norm or a different space).

Does someone have some tips to show this normed vector space is complete? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What "doesn't work with that norm"? Also: Isn't $V$ a closed subspace of $H^1(\Omega)$ (and hence, complete).

Comment: Yes, V is complete with respect to the norm of $H^1$, but I want it complete with respect to the seminorm of $H^1$ (the norm that I listed). I was just looking at the proof with the H^1 norm for ideas, but I don't see how the same idea could work to prove completeness with the seminorm.

Comment: For $u\in V$ you have $u_D = 0$ and then Poincare-Wirtinger gives $\| |\nabla u|\|_{L^2}\leq \|u\|_{H^1} = \|u\|_{L^2} + \| |\nabla u|\|_{L^2} \leq (C+1)\| |\nabla u|\|_{L^2}$, i.e. both norms are equivalent on $V$.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but I wasn't sure $u_D = 0$. Does that work in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I'd like to understand better how the divergence theorem gives that result for $u_{\Omega}$. Does it come from Stoke's Theorem, or one of the other corollaries?
Does the result come from just the hypothesis on the domain $\Omega$ plus the hypothesis on the boundary $\partial \Omega$ that $\int_{\partial \Omega} udx = 0$?

Comment: Oh boy, it seems like I was talking rubbish... $u_D=0$ does not hold...